# Disable repo which is matching the value via ansible

Tags: linux, centos, ansible

This is written incorrectly. we want to disable all repos except the rhel & epel one.

```
- name: yum-clean-metadata
  command: yum clean metadata
  args:
    warn: no

- name: Repos disabled if not rhel.repo
  debug: msg={{ lookup('fileglob', '/etc/yum.repo.d/rhel.repo') }}
  yum:
    name: 
    disablerepo: "ora,ol7_latest"

- name: Ensure the yum package index is up to Date
  yum:
    update_cache: yes
    name: '*'
    state: latest
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting and reword the question.

Comment: Please be more specific with what isn't working. Do you want to disable _all_ repos except the rhel one? Do you want to install ```sos``` from a specific repo?

Comment: Want to disable all repos except the rhel --> Yes Correct

Comment: @spuck do you still have doubt. let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not opposed to manipulating the repo files themselves, this play should rename all `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files except the ones specified in the `allowed_repos` list.

If you know exactly which files you want to disable, the other answer is more straightforward.

```
  - name: Disable extra repositories
    vars:
      allowed_repos:
        - /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
        - /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel.repo
      found_repo_files: []
    block:
      - name: Find all repositories
        find:
          paths: "/etc/yum.repos.d"
          file_type: file
          recurse: no
          patterns: "*.repo"
        register: repos_d

      - name: Compile repository list
        set_fact:
          found_repo_files: "{{ found_repo_files }} + [ '{{ item.path }}' ]"
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ item.path }}"
        with_items:
          - "{{ repos_d.files }}"

      - name: Rename any extra repositories
        when: not ansible_check_mode
        command:
          cmd: "mv {{ item }} {{ item }}.orig"
          removes: "{{ item }}"
        with_items:
          - "{{ found_repo_files | difference(allowed_repos) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for you support, I think this should work. I was lokking to disable repo, but renaming will also work.

Comment: If you would rather disable the repo, replace the move command with a ```lineinfile``` action and set the ```enabled``` flag to 0.

Comment: Disabling the repos can be done with the `ini_file` module, more suited for .repo files than the generic `lineinfile`. Beware that some repo files contain more that one repo and you might want to keep only one of them enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [yum_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html) module to add or remove YUM repositories. According to the examples in the module's documentation you have to set `state: absent` to remove repositories from your system.

So it should probably look like this:

```
- name: Remove repositories ora and ol7_latest
  yum_repository:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
    with_items:
     - ora
     - ol7_latest
```

I don't know which additional repositories are installed on your system. You can run `yum repolist` to see which repositories are installed.

Comment: My requirement is to exclude all those repo which are not in the variable like rhel.repo & epel.repo.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are focusing on totally disabling or removing the repositories. Using `yum_repository` with `state: absent` is one way but then you lost the info if you ever need to re-enable.

A better way IMO is to use [`ini_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html) to manipulate the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files and toggle the `enabled=0` flag wherever it is needed.

Meanwhile, since you did not precise in your question if you wanted the disabled state to persist after your play, here is a solution to achieve your goal in one single task. As you understand, the enabled/disabled repos will only be valid for the time of that single task.

```yaml
- name: update all package using only rhel and epel repositories
  yum:
    disablerepo: "*"
    enablerepo:
      - rhel
      - epel
    name: "*"
    state: latest
```